# Fill Custom TreeView from Database where parents indent by letter

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, treeview

with `DataTable FertSt = dbConn.GetFertSt();` i get the following result:

```
FertSt |  MatNr
BAA    |  123
BAA    |  234
BAB    |  111
BAC    |  123
BBA    |  234
BBB    |  111
BBB    |  123
BCA    |  234
BCD    |  111
CAA    |  123
CAA    |  234
CAB    |  111
```

Now I want to archive a TreeView with checkboxes like so:

```
B
  BA
     BAA
        123
        234
     BAB
        111
     BAC
        123
  BB
     BBA
        234
...
C
```

To create the TreeView i've used this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView

But how can i populate and order the treeview with the subitems?!

Here's how i populate it hardcoded, but i want to take the data from the database:

```
FilterViewModel root = new FilterViewModel("B")
        {
            //IsInitiallySelected = true,
            Children =
            {
                new FilterViewModel("BA")
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new FilterViewModel("BAA"){
                            Children =
                            {
                                new FilterViewModel("111111"),
                                new FilterViewModel("111112"),
                                new FilterViewModel("111113"),
                                new FilterViewModel("111114"),
                            }
                        },
                        new FilterViewModel("BAB"){
                            Children =
                            {
                                new FilterViewModel("211111"),
                                new FilterViewModel("211112"),
                                new FilterViewModel("211114"),
                            }
                        },
                        new FilterViewModel("BAC"),
                    }
                },
                new FilterViewModel("BC")
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new FilterViewModel("BCI"){
                            Children =
                            {
                                new FilterViewModel("112111"),
                                new FilterViewModel("111112"),
                                new FilterViewModel("113113"),
                                new FilterViewModel("111514"),
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                new FilterViewModel("BD")
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new FilterViewModel("BDA"),
                        new FilterViewModel("BDB"),
                        new FilterViewModel("BDC"),
                    }
                },
                new FilterViewModel("BE")
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new FilterViewModel("BEA"),
                        new FilterViewModel("BEB"),
                        new FilterViewModel("BEC"),
                    }
                },
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can load from your database into a List of FilterViewModel, you can then build the hierarchy using a series of dictionaries.

```
var level1Items = new Dictionary<string, FilterViewModel>();
var level2Items = new Dictionary<string, FilterViewModel>();
var level3Items = new Dictionary<string, FilterViewModel>();

Foreach(var item in FilterViewModelList)
{
    var level1Key = item.FertSt.Substring(0,1); 
    if (!level1Items.ContainsKey(level1Key))
        level1Items[level1Key] = new FilterViewModel(level1Key);
    var level1Item = level1Items[level1Key];     

    var level2Key = item.FertSt.Substring(0,2); 
    if (!level2Items.ContainsKey(level2Key))
    {
        level2Items[level2Key] = new FilterViewModel(level2Key);
        level1Item.Children.Add(level2Items[level2Key]);
    }
    var level2Item = level2Items[level2Key];        

    var level3Key = item.FertSt.Substring(0,3); 
    if (!level3Items.ContainsKey(level3Key))
    {
        level3Items[level3Key] = new FilterViewModel(level3Key);
        level2Item.Children.Add(level3Items[level3Key]);
    }
    var level3Item = level3Items[level3Key];        

    level3Item.Children.Add(item);
}
```

You can then use `level1Items.Values` as the `ItemsSource` of your `TreeView`.